# laravel5.1 model relations for guest/auth

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have created Article Model and add method:

```
public function brkon()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Article\ArticleBrkon', 'articles_id', 'article_id')->where('user_id', '=', (int) Auth::user()->user_id);
}
```

but when i'm guest i see error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

I changed brkon for this:

```
public function brkon()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
            return;
    }
    return $this->hasOne('App\Article\ArticleBrkon', 'articles_id', 'article_id')->where('user_id', '=', (int) Auth::user()->user_id);
}
```

and now i have this problem:

> Relationship method must return an object of type
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello as hotfix you can use

```
public function brkon()
{
    $userId = 0;
    if (Auth::user()) {
        $userId = Auth::user()->user_id
    }
    return $this->hasOne('App\Article\ArticleBrkon', 'articles_id', 'article_id')->where('user_id', '=', (int) $userId);
}
```

but I think you have to change logic and allow only authorized users call this model if it's possible

Comment: i can use this or check is authorized user and load another view file. whats better?

Comment: I think better  load another view file because in this case you don't use query to DB and it will be faster.